# grunt-autoprefixer loops endlessly when using grunt-contrib-watch

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm just learning **Grunt**. I'm going to use compass for vertical rhythm and image sprite generation and autoprefixer for prefixing css3 styles.

Here's my **Gruntfile.js**.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var globalConfig = {
    sassDir: 'sass',
    cssDir: 'css'
  };

  require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);
  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    globalConfig: globalConfig,
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    compass: {
      dev: {
        options: {
          sassDir: '<%= globalConfig.sassDir %>',
          cssDir: '<%= globalConfig.cssDir %>'
        }
      }
    },
    autoprefixer: {
      dev: {
        options: {
          browsers: ['last 2 versions']
        },
        src: '<%= globalConfig.cssDir %>/style.css',
        dest: '<%= globalConfig.cssDir %>/style.css'
      }
    },
    watch: {
      compass: {
        files: ['<%= globalConfig.sassDir %>/**/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['compass:dev'],
      },
      autoprefixer: {
        files: ['<%= globalConfig.cssDir %>/style.css'],
        tasks: ['autoprefixer:dev']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: { livereload: true },
        files: ['<%= globalConfig.cssDir %>/style.css']
      }
    }
  });

  // Default task(s) that will be run by invoking 'grunt' w/o args
  grunt.registerTask('styles:dev', ['compass', 'autoprefixer']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['styles:dev', 'watch']);
};
```

But whenever i run

```
grunt
```

Everything works as expected except that grunt-contrib-watch calls grunt-autoprefixer endlessly.

I'm just beginning to learn **Grunt**. It's probably a wrong configuration on my **Gruntfile.js**

I hope you could help me out here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change your task configuration to:

```
watch: {
  compass: {
    files: ['<%= globalConfig.sassDir %>/**/*.scss'],
    tasks: ['compass:dev', 'autoprefixer:dev']
  },
  livereload: {
    options: { livereload: true },
    files: ['<%= globalConfig.cssDir %>/style.css']
  }
}
```

Basically, grunt-contrib-watch will run tasks whenever a file is updated, and because your source and destination files are the same it turns it into an infinite loop. Simply run the autoprefixing once your compass task has built your css. Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: if you don't mind, would you share some best practices tips with configuring gruntfile.js?
:)

thanks.

Comment: Once you get used to configuring tasks, you'll find a load of different plugins that can automate all sorts of common development work. There's not really many best practices that I can refer you to in this instance, you've already set up a config for common directories, used the matchdep trick etc. I've found that it's all fairly straightforward to get working, providing that you read the documentation for each plugin. Definitely browse through the npm repository for new plugins though, there's a lot to discover :-)